# Regex multiple matches on same line

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following JavaScript Regex

As used in http://regexpal.com/

`\[.*(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.bmp|\.jpeg).*\]`

As use in jQuery code -

`post.html().match(/\[.*(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.bmp|\.jpeg).*\]/g);`

This is the sample data I am working with

> 1. [cid:image001.jpg@01CD2DC8.704399C0]
> 2. s[cid:image001.png@01CD2DC8.704399C0]<
> 3. image.jpg
> 4. [cid:image002.jpg@01CD2DC8.704399C0]
> 5. [cid:image002.exe@01CD2DC8.704399C0]
> 6. [cid:image002.gif@01CD2DC8.704399C0]
> 7. [[cid:image001.jpg@01CD2DE6.9802A2D0]
>    And again
>    [cid:image002.png@01CD2DE6.9802A2D0]]
> 8. test.gif

My issue is that on line 7, I would like the two strings enclosed in the [] to be separate, at the moment it is treating the whole line as a match,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to modify your regexp to change the greediness (note the `.*?`):

```
\[.*?(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.bmp|\.jpeg).*?\]
```